Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value (overshot)
I'm trying to automate the calculation of gas based on the balance, set the required gas and send the remaining balance. Am I misunderstanding something?
// send all
const amount = balance.weiBalance - Number(gasPrice) * gasLimit;

Getting this error:

Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value:
balance 707225000000000, queued cost 707224970000000, tx cost
707225000000000, overshot 707224970000000

async function send(account, balance) {
    // Calculate gas
    const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address);
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const gasLimit = 21000;

    // send all
    const amount = balance.weiBalance - Number(gasPrice) * gasLimit;

    // Create raw transaction
    let rawTx = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count + 1),
        to: TO_ADDRESS,
        from: account.address,
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
        value: web3.utils.toHex(amount),
    };

    // Sign raw transaction
    const tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    const privateKey = Buffer.from(account.privateKey, "hex");
    tx.sign(privateKey);

    // Serialize transaction
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString("hex");
    console.log("tx", serializedTx);

    // Send signed transaction
    try {
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedTx}`);
        console.log("Transaction Successful...");
        console.log("Receipt:", JSON.stringify(receipt, null, "\t"));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Unable to send transaction", error);
    }
}


On which chain you're doing the transaction? Is it an L2?

Tbh, not sure what L2 means. I'm trying to transfer Ether to a different wallet.

I mean, on what network? Is it Ethereum, Base, Arbitrum, Optimism, Polygon, etc?

The nonce is wrong it should be nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count).
